# Checkmark not responding when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have the following link that when you click on it,it changes my checkmark colour. as follows

```css
.checkmark {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    /* height: 22px; */
    height: 17px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

    .checkmark:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 3px;
        height: 9px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        left: 11px;
        top: 6px;
    }

.checkmark {
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .checkmark:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 3px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        left: 8px;
        top: 12px;
    }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:after {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label  dataid="' + this.MarketID + '"><input type= "checkbox" style= "display:none;" id="cb' + this.MarketID + '" >Click Me<span for="cb' + this.MarketID + '" class="checkmark"></span ></label >
```

the problem i am having is that when i add an onclick function to my label the checkmark stops resonding as follows:

```js
function followInternalink(event) {
            var link = $(event.target).closest('label');
            
            var destination = link.attr('data-destination');
            if ((destination == 'null' || destination == 'local') && link.attr('dataid')) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var id = link.attr('dataid');
                navigateToEvent(id);
            }
            else {
            //does something else
            }
            }
```

```css
.checkmark {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22px;
    /* height: 22px; */
    height: 17px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

    .checkmark:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 3px;
        height: 9px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        left: 11px;
        top: 6px;
    }

.checkmark {
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .checkmark:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 3px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        left: 8px;
        top: 12px;
    }

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:before,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+.checkmark:after {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label onclick="followInternalink(event)" data-destination="local" dataid="' + this.MarketID + '" ><input type= "checkbox" style= "display:none;" id="cb' + this.MarketID + '" >Click Me<span for="cb' + this.MarketID + '" class="checkmark"></span ></label >
```

the above function works as i want it to,it just stops checking the checkmark, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `navigateToEvent()` is undefined?

Comment: If you are preventing default your click on the label might not trigger the change event on the checkbox. try locating the related checkbox to the label and setting its `checked` property then your CSS should do the rest.

Comment: @FrancisLeigh navigateToEvent() is another function i call,its just telling you undefined here because i didnt add it

Comment: Like said below, try removing `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: that worked thank you,didnt even notice that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `event.preventDefault();` which may be the reason you native HTML behaviour stopped working